# Expand existing RAID1 zpool into RAID10 zpool

Tags: zfs, raid10, zfsonlinux, zpool, convert

I'd like to expand/convert my existing RAID1 (2x 3TB mirror) zpool to RAID10 zpool by adding 2 more 3TB HDDs without losing (or moving) data stored on my existing pool.

The final result will look like 2x3TB (existing mirror) + 2x3TB (new mirror) combined into RAID0 zpool

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The incantation you are looking for is:

`zpool add poolname mirror newdisk1 newdisk2`